# In AWS CDK, how do you restrict a Transfer User to their assigned home directory?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-transfer-family

When using the AWS console to configure a Transfer Family User for an sFTP server, there is a 'Restricted' checkbox that prevents the user from moving out of their home directory.

[image]

I am trying to configure a user with the Python CDK (v2.61), but there is no 'restricted' parameter. I've read online that using a `home_directory_mapping` in the following way when creating the user can achieve the same result:

```py
home_directory_mappings=[
  transfer.CfnUser.HomeDirectoryMapEntryProperty(
    entry="/",
    target="/<bucket_name>/<folder_name>"
  )
]
```

Unfortunately this does not seem to work - I am still able to `cd ..` and the 'Restricted' checkbox does not end up checked.

Does anyone know how to configure this option in CDK?

Answer (score 2):

Since this is an L1 construct, it works exactly the same as in CloudFormation. Set the [`HomeDirectoryType`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-transfer-user.html#cfn-transfer-user-homedirectorytype) to `LOGICAL` in order to get the chroot jail effect.

You must also ensure that the directory exists first, otherwise the mapping has no effect.

In many cases, you'll want the attached [policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-transfer-user.html#cfn-transfer-user-homedirectorytype) to also prohibit access outside of desired S3 directories, which will also prevent access via `cd ..` even if you don't configure the chroot jail ("restricted") access.

Answer (score 2):

After the answer from sytech, and some further experimenting, I came up with a satisfactory solution:

1. Set `home_directory_type` to `LOGICAL`
2. Use the `home_directory_mappings` as in my original post
3. DO NOT set `home_directory`

I followed these 3 points and now the 'Restricted' checkbox shows up.

```py
transfer.CfnUser(
  scope=self,
  id=id_,
  # DO NOT user home_directory
  home_directory_type="LOGICAL",
  home_directory_mappings = [
    transfer.CfnUser.HomeDirectoryMapEntryProperty(
        entry="/",
        target="/<bucket_name>/<folder_name>"
    )
  ]
)
```

Comment: Glad you were able to figure that out -- not setting the `home_directory` is a good callout.... Though in your original question, you didn't mention you were specifying `home_directory` ;)